# Scroll view scroll indicator visible despite being turned off

Tags: ios

I've just added a UIScrollView and when the user scrolls (horizontally) the scroll bar indicator appears at the bottom of the screen (then it disappears when the user stops scrolling).
However in the VC's viewDidLoad I'm setting the SC's showsHorizontalScrollIndicator to NO, also in IB in the Shows Horizonal Scrollers check box is set to off.

So how can I make these scroll indicators permanently never appear?

Comment: are you sure you are not creating a new instance of that scrollView (allocing/initing) after you have set the showsHorizontalScrollIndicator to NO?

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal and vertical indicators are type of UIImageView by default. So, if you want to remove it permanently then do this

```
//Assuming myScrollView is of type UIScrollView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     for(UIView *subview in myScrollView.subviews){
         [subview removeFromSuperview]; 
     }
}
```